# Can I perform operations between rows on a dataframe?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a dataframe

```
   ID1  ID2 x             y          time
0   0   1   34.337735   -76.3319716667  1446797582
1   0   1   34.3841816667   -76.2837666667  1446796183
2   0   2   34.49157    -76.1661133333  1446792969
3   0   3   34.5275266667   -76.1151866667  1446791765
4   0   3   34.5624816667   -76.0633883333  1446790559
```

What I would like is to capture the distance moved by each member, identified uniquely by the `ID1,ID2` pair.

Is there anyway I can perform row operations on a dataframe?  My initial idea was to convert the dataframe to a matrix using `df.as_matrix()`, pick out the unique IDs, an compute distances from the matrix.

This seems really inefficient.  Is there a better way I could do this with dataframes?

Comment: Are there multiple rows of data for each ID1, ID2 pair ? In other words are x and y changing with time?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  For arbitrary ID1,ID2 pair, there is atleast one row.  If there are multiple, the x,y change with time.

Comment: Probably a convoluted way of doing it, but You could `groupby` ID1 and ID2; then *iterate over the groups*  zipping (use `zip`) `x` and `y` into a `xy` column where values are points (x,y). Then, shifting this `xy` column by 1 (use `shift`), get a new column `xyshift`. Then apply a difference function in the row-axis in this `xyshift` column; and finally merge it iteratively into your dataframe or compose a new one

Answer (score 1):

if you want to calculate the distance for each time step you can do the following

`df[['x' , 'y']].apply(lambda x : np.linalg.norm(x) , axis = 1 )`

on the other hand if you want to calculate the distance by each member you can do the following

```
In [38]:
df.groupby([df.ID1 , df.ID2])[['x' , 'y']].
apply(lambda x : np.linalg.norm(x.diff().dropna())  if len(x) > 1 else 0 )
Out[38]:
ID1  ID2
0    1      0.066940
     2      0.000000
     3      0.062489
dtype: float64
```

first you will group by your `ID` columns and then check for the members length if the length is greater than `1` so this means the member has moved other wise the member didn't .

you can calculate the difference between `x` and `y` by using the `diff` function which will produce `na` for the first columns but you can drop it easily using `dropna` function .

then to calculate the vector length you can easily use the function `np.linalg.norm`

you can also use `x.diff().iloc[1]` instead of `x.diff().dropna()`

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I don't want the total distance traveled by each member.  I instead want the distance traveled in each time step.

Comment: this is even pretty much easier , instead you can use `df[['x' , 'y']].apply(lambda x : np.linalg.norm(x)  , axis = 1 )`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the length of a total path for each unique pair you could do

```
pd.DataFrame(df.groupby(['ID1','ID2']).apply(lambda z:pathlength(z.x.values,z.y.values)))
```

Where `pathlength` is

```
from math import sqrt
def pathlength(x,y):
    n = len(x) 
    lv = [sqrt((x[i]-x[i-1])**2 + (y[i]-y[i-1])**2) for i in range (1,n)]
    L = sum(lv)
    return L
```

That gives us

```
    0
ID1 ID2 
0   1   0.066940
    2   0.000000
    3   0.062489
```